# What does tt & 0 stands for in this line?

Tags: c#

What does tt & 0 stands for in this line?

```
 Time = string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
```

I looked here but didn't see anything : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.format.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `0` is the placeholder for the value of the first `format` parameter - it stand for the value of `DateTime.Now` in your example. This is part of [composite format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

The `tt` is part of the [Custom Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

`tt` is for the AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 1):

0 -  here is the part of Index number of for the object that is to be formatted as string for the given parameter (which in your case is DateTime.Now)

tt - here denotes the AM/PM value.

[More Info about 'tt' format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ttSpecifier)